# Integrating Twitter Bootstrap easily to any Pyramid form framework

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, pyramid, mongoengine

I am building a web service based on Pyramid, MongoEngine and Twitter Bootstrap. It contains only few simple forms. What could be the best way to implement forms, so that they intergrate well with Twitter Bootstrap? Mostly I am worried about need to hack all the HTML together by hand myself.

- What Pyramid frameworks play nicely with Bootstrap out of the box with add-ons?
- In the case I need to spread CSS classes etc. stuff all over the templates what could be the easiest approach for this?

I am using MongoEngine models, but there are only very small number of those and adapting them to form framework is easy.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on such an old thread. How did your project turn out? Currently working with pyramid and sql alchemy but to create a data driven website

Comment: We made GBP 9 million revenue last year http://tokenmarket.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deform with deform_bootstrap is a reasonable choice.

deform_bootstrap: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform_bootstrap

You can take a look at what it looks like here:

http://deformdemo.xo7.de/

Comment: How come my all problems have been solved with Pyramid before I even think about them?

Comment: deform_bootstrap is outdated and uses bootstrap 2. deform 2 uses bootstrap 3 by default - http://deform2demo.repoze.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [deform_jinja2](https://github.com/sontek/deform_jinja2)